# Bigquery clustering by PK

Tags: google-bigquery, cluster-analysis

I have a Big query table with integer `id` column that is unique. Table is not partitioned. Most queries use `id` column in where clause to filter. I thought that clustering by `id` will decrease data scanned. But its not the case.
So when i ran a query like `select * from table where id=59804`, regardless of whether the table is clustered by id or not.
Could someone pls help understanding why doesn't clustering work in this case?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by partitioning the table first before clustering. If you don't have a date or timestamp, you can create a fake date column of type date with all values as null and use it as a partition key. Without partitioning and with only clustering, I didn't see any less bytes processed. With both though, bytes processed were reduced up to almost 90%

[image]

[image]